# Gradle append zip archive

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I need to add file to existing zip archive. I tried to use Gradle Zip Task but it overwrite my archive.

I have now solved the problem as follows

```
import java.nio.file.FileSystem
import java.nio.file.FileSystems
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.util.function.Consumer

task AddToZip() {
  doLast {
    FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(Paths.get("$pathToZip"), null)
    Files.walk(Paths.get("$rootDir/dir")).forEach(new Consumer<java.nio.file.Path>() {
      @Override
      void accept(java.nio.file.Path path) {
        java.nio.file.Path dest = fs.getPath(path.toString().substring("$rootDir".length()))
        if (path.toFile().isDirectory()) {
          Files.createDirectory(dest)
          return
        }
        Files.copy(path, dest)
      }
    })
    fs.close()
  }
}
```

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Project.zipTree(...)` to create a `FileTree` from the original zip. This can then be passed to `Zip.from(...)`

```
task addToZip(type:Zip) {
   from zipTree('path/to/original.zip')
   from 'path/to/additional/file.txt'
   archiveFileName = "updated.zip"
   destinationDirectory = file("$buildDir/zips")
}
```

- See [Project.zipTree(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#zipTree-java.lang.Object-)
- See [AbstractCopyTask.from(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html#from-java.lang.Object...-)

Comment: I tried your solution. Without zipTree works fine (overwrite old archive). But when i used zipTree: Could not expand ZIP <pathToZip>. Cause: archive is not a ZIP archive. Old archive created by previous Gradle task to which I attach my task addToZip using finalizedBy

Comment: If `zipTree(...)` can't convert your zip to a `FileTree` then either the file is not a zip, or you've configured the path incorrectly. Are you sure it's a zip? (perhaps it's a `.tar.gz`)

Comment: this file is created by ZipOutputStream in another task, OS also recognize file as Zip Archive. Path i set as follows: from zipTree("$buildDir/archive.zip") and i use same path in my solution with FileSystem class

Comment: Everything you need to do with files is available via Gradle APIs, you should never need to use `ZipOutputStream` in any Gradle tasks

Comment: Unfortunately this is a third party plugin, so i cant change it.